# Django select_for_update function in concurrent process

Tags: python, mysql, django, transactions

When I testing the function of `update_or_create` in multi threading condition, I found the result is not what I wanted,they created more than one record in MySQL. As the code show, `update_or_create` used `select .. for update` to lock rows in MySQL, then it should be only one record in MySQL. I used SQLAlchemy and row sql has proved that.

So, is the Django codes wrong?

with Django code:

```py
def get_or_create_ins():
    p, created = OxalicAcid.objects.update_or_create(defaults={"formula": "20", "degree": "80"}, name="smart")

def run():
    for i in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=get_or_create_ins, args=())
        t.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # more than one record will be created
    run()
```

with SQLAlchemy code:

```py
@contextmanager
def transaction_atomic():
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        raise e


def get_result_with_update(session, name):
    sql = text("""
        select * from acid_oxalicacid where name = :name for update 
    """)
    params = dict(name=name)
    cursor = session.execute(sql, params)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


def get_result(session, name):
    sql = text("""
        select * from acid_oxalicacid where name = :name
    """)
    params = dict(name=name)
    cursor = session.execute(sql, params)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


def create_data(session, name, degree, formula):
    sql = text("""
        insert into acid_oxalicacid (name, degree, formula) values (:name, :degree, :formula)
    """)
    params = dict(
        name=name,
        degree=degree,
        formula=formula
    )
    session.execute(sql, params)


def get_or_create():
    name = "smart"
    degree = "50"
    formula = "100"

    with transaction_atomic() as session:
        res = get_result_with_update(session, name)
        if not res:
            create_data(session, name, degree, formula)
            res = get_result(session, name)
        return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Only one record be created, that's correct 
    for i in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=get_or_create, args=())
        t.start()
```

Comment: See the warning in [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) - if you don’t have a unique constraint in the database, then `get_or_create` and `update_or_create` can result in multiple rows.

Comment: @Alasdair I have read the docs, but I want to know Django `select_for_update`  what really do. When I invoke `print(connection.quires)`, the SQL actually used `FOR UPDATE`, but why it's stilly creates multiply records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Django use the 'read committed' transaction isolation level, so it will be multiply records, if change it to 'repeatable read', it's will be only one record in database.